# How to plot multiple line graph for a column value from a CSV file?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, matplotlib

I tried to plot a graph for energies of 4 nodes using line graph but I'm not able to identify which line represent which node ID(1,2,3 or 4)

My csv looks something like this :

`Time,Source,Destination,Bits,Energy
0,1,2,288,9.9999856
1058,1,2,288,9.9999856
1140,2,1,96,9.9999808
1958,2,3,96,9.9999952
2024,2,1,96,9.9999808
2051,2,3,288,9.999966399
3063,2,3,288,9.9999808
3126,3,2,96,9.999976
3127,2,1,288,9.9999664
3946,3,2,96,9.999961599
8340,1,2,288,9.999952
9418,1,2,288,9.999947199
9479,2,1,96,9.999942399
10299,2,3,96,9.9999712
10365,2,1,96,9.9999472
10758,2,3,288,9.999927999
11770,2,3,288,9.9999568
11832,3,2,96,9.999951999
11842,2,1,288,9.9999328`

Code :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('DS1.csv')

for Energy,data in df.groupby('Source'):
    plt.plot(data['Time'], data['Energy'])
    plt.legend(data['Source'])
    #print(data)

plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Energy')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I actually want to plot source,energy vs Time for all sources(1 to 4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the label.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('DS1.csv')

for Energy, data in df.groupby('Source'):
    plt.plot(data['Time'], data['Energy'], label=Energy)
    #print(data)

plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Energy')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```